# Xamarin Resource designer does not update properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, resources

I have a Visual Studio solution containing a Xamarin Android project.

Since the migration to VS17, the Resource designer from Xamarin started behaving strangely.

If I add a new XML layout in the Resources/layout folder, the Resource Designer will only notice it after I exclude, and re-include the new file.

However, if these steps are reproduced with a second new file, the Resource designer will notice the second new file, but the first one will be erased.

This makes refactoring impossible, and leads to completely corrupted project.

Has anyone a workaround for this ?

Visual studio 2017 entreprise version : 15.3.0
Xamarin version : 4.6.0.295 (306f67a)

Comment: Did you check the 'BuildAction' of that first file?

Comment: @ThomasDeWilde the build action is set on TransformFile. Should I check another ? I don't know what these actions are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, files in the Resources folder should have its build action set to 'AndroidResource' in order for the Resource Designer to notice them.

So when you add existing files, make sure the build action is also set properly.

Same goes for files in the resource folder on iOS.
Only, the build actions is called 'BundleResource'.